Can I open more than 1 app store/google play account with the same details?
We're an agency and we build apps for people. People come to us to build apps for them and upload them to the app store, and google play store.
We want to use the same details when opening an account, like the same credit card and same address and so on.
The emails can be different, but the card details, addresses, legal information all are same for the different accounts.
We're willing to pay the $25 fee and the $99/year subscription fees too for each account.
